# What data type and index to use for a searchable userName column in a MySQL database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, sqldatatypes, database-indexes

I have a MySQL database that has a InnoDB table called `user`.

Each user is required to create a user name during the creation of the account. The user name can only be between 1 and 40 characters (utf-8) long. The purpose of this user name is to allow for one user to search for another.

The problem is that I am not sure what datatype to use for the user name. Since the user name will be variable length a `Varchar` seems fitting but I am uncertain on how fast it is to index and do searches on a `Varchar`. The thought I had is that because I know the maximum character length I could use a `Char(40)` instead. Although this would waste some space due to the padding I would imagine it would make indexing and searching faster and more efficient since it is fixed length.

The other aspect I am uncertain about is if I should use a `Fulltext` index or a `BTree` index for this user name column. Or if there is an other index method I don't know about that would work better.

So which datatype in correlation with which index would give me the best, fastest and most scalable solution to this ?

Comment: how many  millons on of user you think to store  .. ??'

Comment: If all goes well somewhere around 15-20million, just to be prepared

Comment: you can use varchar for this  ..

Comment: So Char would get no speed or scalability advantages ?

Comment: there is not appreciable vantage  ..

Comment: Cool thanks XD, If you could maybe explain in a bit more detail what your reasoning is I would appreciate it as it would help me understand;

Comment: For the kind of index, depend of what you'll use to search: if it's beginning of the string for 99.9% case, then BTree. If you go for a `*pattern*` search every time, then a BTree will not even by used...

Comment: char field allocates exact bytes for each row, varchar has completely different story in your case, as it will reduce the file site for millions of rows

Comment: Ok so varchar is just more space efficient for my need then. So if it is a pattern type search do I need to index the column at all?

Comment: No, if you are intending such patterns %LIKE%, indexes are from the start of the string till the end

Comment: Perfect, that was very helpful. So `Varchar` and no index it is then XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Char vs Varchar

Char is useful when you have a fixed length, like with product reference or ISO-* field. Why ? because it'll spare you the use of a *length byte* on every line.

But in your case, the name will mostly never be over 20char, so to spare a single byte you'll burn more than 20 in 75% of your records: not the good way.

Varchar, definitely.

---

## Index BTree vs FullText

Next, the index. As said, it depend of what kind of search you'll do.

For search that use `='pattern'` or `LIKE 'pattern%'` the BTree index is really the best.

For search that only do `LIKE '%pattern%'` to search a *partial sub string* in a string, then, you don't really have anything.

The best you can do is having a "small" table that just map `id = name`, make your search on it and hope mysql will keep it in RAM to do the sequential read.

And last, you spoke about Fulltext index: this index is best suited for matching a word or begging of word in a text, so probably the same result than a BTree for you.

So, what the best way ?

Probably a BTree index. Yes you'll not cover the search inside the word, but for most case it'll be enough.

How to use it the best way ?

- Run a first search with `LIKE 'pattern%'`
- You have a result ? then this is probably what the user want
- No ? Go for a much slower `LIKE '%pattern%'`

Improvement :

- allowing the user to check an "inside word" modifier that go straight to the second search
- fixing a minimal number of line for the first query to avoid the 2nd and not just a strict 0 result

Answer (score 0):

```
username VARCHAR(40) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL

INDEX(username)

WHERE username = 'some_username'
```

This is the only sane answer.  You need up to 40 UTF-8 characters.  Users will search only for full names, no partial stuff (`LIKE`, `FULLTEXT`, etc).  You need to index, so don't worry that it is slightly less efficient than `INT`.

One possible variation:  You may want `username` to be the `PRIMARY KEY` (instead of a 'secondary' `INDEX`) in some table.